# Order a Django model by foreign key's column without joining foreign key table?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I order a model with respect to a foreign key's column without joining in the foreign key table?

For example, if I have:

```
class WidgetType(Model):
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = CharField(max_length=16)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["label"]

class Widget(Model):
    type = ForeignKey(WidgetType)
```

How can I generate the query:

```
SELECT * FROM widgets_widget ORDER BY type_id
```

Without joining in the foreign key table?

It seems like the `<fk>_id` can't be used:

```
>>> Widget.objects.all().order_by("type_id")
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'type_id' into field. Choices are: type
```

Using `<fk>__id` seems to join in, and then ignore, the FK table:

```
>>> print Widget.objects.all().order_by("type").query
SELECT * FROM widgets_widget
LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets_widgettype ON …
ORDER BY widgets_widget.type_id
```

And using `<fk>` uses the foreign key model's default ordering:

```
>>> print Widget.objects.all().order_by("type").query
SELECT * FROM widgets_widget
LEFT OUTER JOIN widgets_widgettype ON …
ORDER BY widgets_widgettype.label
```

Comment: Which version of django you are using? It seems only  django1.7 provide order_by feature with no join, you can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: This is Django 1.5. Testing with Django 1.7 produces an identical result.

Comment: Ah, yes, but it does look like `.order_by("type_id")` would be valid in 1.7!

Comment: Yes, it looks like the documentation is misleading on this front. I've opened a ticket here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23774

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Django 1.7, please refer to Geo Jacob's answer - it's included.
If not, and if you don't need object instances, you could help yourself with `values()`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)


>>> qs = UserProfile.objects.all().values('user', 'country').order_by('user')
>>> print qs.query
SELECT `userprofiles_userprofile`.`user_id`, `userprofiles_userprofile`.`country` FROM `userprofiles_userprofile` ORDER BY `userprofiles_userprofile`.`user_id` ASC
>>> qs
[{'country': u'AT', 'user': 1L}, {'country': u'AT', 'user': 18L}, {'country': u'RU', 'user': 19L}, [...]
```

Comment: add @David Wolever to blacklist :D

Comment: Not my downvote, but this answer also isn't correct. When you `.order_by('user')` the default ordering for the `User` model will be used; see the example in my question.

Comment: Disagree; my proposed way works, as you can get from the example. `values` in combination with order_by avoids the join.